# Can i use a GPLv2 module in my commercial application?

Tags: copyright, software, gpl

I am developing a commercial wordpress plugin. There is a form module that i have to develop however, i found one already built under GPL2 here

https://github.com/weDevsOfficial/weforms

All other modules are developed by me, i just wanted to integrate this form module in it. Can i sell my application if i use this?

Answer (score 7):

No version of the GPL forbids selling software.  If you're merging other software with it, the whole thing has to be under GPLv2, so other people can use and distribute it as they like, and you need to provide source code.  This may not fit your business model.

Comment: I have someone saying otherwise on quora

https://www.quora.com/Can-software-licensed-under-the-GPLv2-be-modified-and-then-sold-for-commercial-gain.

I am really confused now.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan quora says the same thing.  You can integrate and sell it, but you can't keep anyone you sell it to from giving it away for free.

Comment: @dsolimano but do i have to open source all my modules? I mean by terms of license i should only open source what is under GPLv2 so i am not liable to open source the modules those i developed myself. Am i right?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan If your code is derived from GPLv2 code (e.g. by using GPLv2 modules) then you can only publish your code under the terms of the GPLv2. So yes, you must provide the source code without restrictions to anyone who legally obtains a copy of your software. This still doesn't prevent you from selling your software, although it's a less attractive business model. All Wordpress plugins have this dilemma, most solve it by not selling the plugin itself but by selling updates, support, or other external services.

Comment: Well! i am looking at it from wordpress perspective and how other sellers are doing business. Apparently, wordpress itself is licensed under GPL and that means every plugin that is created for wordpress platform should be licensed under GPL. I happened to see Gravity-forms (A paid plugin) license and its GNU. Well, the nature of wordpress platform is such that there is no way you can hide your code even if you wanted to. So i guess i will follow your advice and put my effort in support and updates department.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan Well, you can attempt to hide your code by obfuscation. Occasionally plugin authors try this, but it is forbidden by the GPL license. To comply with the GPL you must release the source code in the preferred form to make changes to the software (pre-obfuscation).